# Chi-Square distance in python between two matrix

Tags: chi-squared

I have two matrix with dimension 36608*1. I want to take a Chi-Square distance between two matrix I have search for Chi-Square method but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Try reshape them as `2*36608` matrix
If you are familiar with python,
you can use `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency`, this function will return `Chi-Square` distance.